# Rails complex query with multi level associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a deeply nested layout as follows:

Contract -> has many Packages -> has many Services

Payment -> belongs_to Invoice -> belongs_to Contract

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
  has_many :contract_packages
  has_many :packages, through: :contract_packages
end

class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
  has_many :contract_packages
  has_many :contracts, through: :contract_packages
end

class ContractPackage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :package
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contract
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

I want to find what Services, and how many times were invoiced in a certain period of time, based on payment date. Invoice date may not be the same as payment date.

I know hot to do it by pure SQL, and it works, but I am stuck if I want to do it the rails way.

Any ideas?

Edit:

The pure sql query:

```
select s.[name], count(*), s.[price] from payments p 
left join invoices i on p.invoice_id=i.id
left join contracts c on i.[contract_id]=c.id
left join contract_packages cp on cp.contract_id=c.id
left join packages pk on cp.[package_id]=pk.id
left join services s on s.package_id=pk.id
where ... conditions
group by s.id
order by s.id asc
```

In my original question I left out, for brevity, a join table, because a package may belong to many contracts. The sql here includes the join table. I updated the models also.

Comment: Can you put the pure SQL way here?  That would help a lot.  And for the record you can convert SQL queries to Arel queries ready for Rails with this site: http://www.scuttle.io/

Answer (score 0):

Doing joins in in activerecord is quite straight forward as long as you have defined the relationships in your models. You just pass a hash to `joins` and it figures out what keys to use. Adding the where conditions can be done in similar fashion.

I noticed that there was no `has_many :payments` in your invoice is this by design? In that case why?

The select clause I have written will give all Service objects created with this query an extra method `count` where you will find your value.

```
Service.select('*, count(*) as count')
.joins({ 
  package: { 
    contract: {
      invoices: :payment
    } 
  }
})
.where(conditions_hash)
.group('services.id asc')
.order(:id)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. One invoice has only one payment, that's why I have no `has_many :payments`.